# How To check whether there is a node inside a node in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

This is a part of my XML code, there are 85 `w:p` nodes in my XML but only few `<w:p>` nodes have `w:listPr` child nodes (as shown below).

I need code in PHP that can check each `<w:p>` node whether it has a `w:listPr` child node, if it has "perform specific task" else "perform another task".. so please help me i am stuck in this for one week.

> This is the code i tried for converting XML to HTML from PHP . iam not getting how to check whether node exits inside a node

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test3.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace("w", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml");
$x = new DOMXpath($doc);
$x->registerNamespace("wx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint");

for($i=0;$i<85;$i++){   
    $errorNodes = $x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('w:listPr');

    if($errorNodes){echo ('li there'); }    else{ echo ('li not there');}
            $no_of_childs =  $x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->childNodes->length;
            if($no_of_childs>3){
                if(($x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle")->item($i)->attributes[0]->nodeValue)==2){
                    echo "<h1>".$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->nodeValue."</h1>";
                }
                else if(($x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle")->item($i)->attributes[0]->nodeValue)==3){
                    echo "<h2>".$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->nodeValue."</h2>";
                }
                else if($no_of_childs==5){
                    echo "<h3>".$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->nodeValue."</h3>";
                }       

            }
        else{
            echo "<p>".$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p")->item($i)->nodeValue."</p>";
        }


    }

?>




<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>In a normal joint, articular cartilage allows for smooth movement within the joint, whereas in an arthritic knee the cartilage itself becomes thinner or completely absent. In addition, the bones become thicker around the edges of the joint and may form bony “spurs”. These factors can cause pain and restricted range of motion in the joint.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Your doctor may advise total knee replacement if you have:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:listPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
                <w:ilfo w:val="1" />
        </w:listPr>
        <w:ind w:left="993" />
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Severe knee pain which limits your daily activities (such as walking, getting up from a chair or climbing stairs).</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? We're here to help you find mistakes in your code, not to write code for you.

Comment: I made some edits to your code, but it would help if you could reformat the code with proper indentation to make it more readable. Thanks.

Comment: should i also need to post complete XML document @Twinfriends

Comment: @manoj NoI think its fine the way it is right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i tried for checking a node inside a node

```
    <?php for($i=0;$i<85;$i++){ 
$gh=$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p[".($i+1)."]/w:pPr/w:listPr/w:ilvl")->item(0)->attributes[0]->nodeValue;
    $g5=$x->evaluate("//wx:sect/w:p[".$i."]/w:pPr/w:listPr")->item(0)->childNodes->length;
    if($gh!=null){
        echo 'exist at paragrah number '.$i." value :".$gh."<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo 'notexist at paragrah number '.$i." value :".$gh."<br>";
    }
} ?>
```